# Formatting just Minutes and Seconds Data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I am doing an analysis of NBA players, and I am running into trouble with the data sets "Minutes Played". The data is in a .csv file but I have read it in as a data frame and tibble. The column contains the minutes and seconds a particular player played that game, but there are a variety of formats given (see picture). I have been trying with no avail to get R to recognize the column as minutes and seconds (really only need minutes if that matters), so I can perform some filtering (ie keep only the players that played at least 24 minutes).

I have tried variations of the POSIX function and searched the web for  help but to no avail.

```
players$MIN <- as.POSIXct(players$MIN, "%H:%M:%S")
players$MIN<-format(.POSIXct(dt,tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")
```

I would appreciate any help I could get- thanks

[Raw Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxlPU.png)

Comment: What is the difference between ##:##:## and ##:##? Is one hours, minutes, and seconds and the other minutes and seconds? Provide data using `dput()` not a picture since that hides important information about the original data. Since you do not have dates, you will probably want to parse out the parts and multiply hours by 60, minutes by 1, and seconds by 1/60.

Comment: I would also check out the R package `nbastatR` or other API's for better data quality.

Answer (score 0):

Given some examples like:

```
df <- data.frame(MIN = c("36:22:00", "23:54", "0:25"))
```

You could split into columns at the `:` like so:

```
tidyr::separate(df, MIN, c("M", "S", "frac"), sep = ":", convert = TRUE)
#   M  S frac
#1 36 22    0
#2 23 54   NA
#3  0 25   NA
```

or to get decimal minutes:

```
library(dplyr)
tidyr::separate(df, MIN, c("M", "S", "frac"), sep = ":", convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(M_frac = M + S/60)

#   M  S frac     M_frac
#1 36 22    0 36.3666667
#2 23 54   NA 23.9000000
#3  0 25   NA  0.4166667
```